# Running beacon node using prysm

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodes, sepolia, prysm

I was running Running beacon node using prysm with the following command:

```
~/Documents/microverse/BlockChain\ and\ Web3/mynode/sepolia/consensus/prysm/prysm.sh beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551 --sepolia --suggested-fee-recipient=0xbce5b6db0b0f77a05a8e2bbf3818669bbdaa496b --jwt-secret="/home/henok/Documents/microverse/BlockChain and Web3/mynode/sepolia/geth/jwtsecret" --genesis-state=genesis.ssz
```

And I get error and terminated:

```
INFO node: Default fee recipient is set to 0xBCE5B6DB0b0F77A05A8E2BbF3818669BbDaa496b, recipient may be overwritten from validator client and persist in db. Default fee recipient will be used as a fall back
error preparing to initialize genesis db state from local ssz files: error checking existence of ssz-encoded file genesis.ssz for genesis state init: stat genesis.ssz: no such file or directory
```

`genesis.ssz` is present in the `/sepolia/consensus/prysm` directory.I cannot figure out what went wrong. This is my first time trying to deploy an Ethereum smart contract using a local Ethereum node.